# On Click on Buttons when created on the fly

Tags: jquery

I have two button classes, when clicked, I want something to happen.

I have:

```
$('.btn-comment, .btn-youtube').click(function(){
```

This used to work when the buttons were static. They are now created ad hoc.

I have tried this:

```
$('.btn-comment, .btn-youtube').on('click', function(){
```

But no luck.

Comment: You need to bind events, or delegate events, to ancestor elements that exist in the DOM at the point of binding.

Comment: Asked hundred times a week...

Comment: Do they have the same id as it in `$('.btn-comment, .btn-youtube').on('click', function(){`?

Comment: @hima there is no selector targeting ID here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to register the handler on a common *static* ancestor (worst case `document`, but the nearer the better) and then use the new `.on` syntax for delegated handlers, e.g.:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-comment, .btn-youtube', function() { 
     ...
});
```

Comment: So if they are in a list it would be better to do: $('#myList').on('click', '.btn-comment, .btn-youtube', function(){

Comment: @panthro indeed, unless the list element itself is also dynamically replaced.  The common ancestor must be _static_.

Answer (score 1):

That's not how it works.
You should add the delegation to the parent element. The one who is going to suffer from modification.

You can do it with the whole document:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-comment, .btn-youtube', function(){ ... });
```

But it would be better to do it with the modified element.

Comment: Stack Overflow needs a *sticky* in each tag. jQuery Event Delegation should be it.

Comment: @RGraham what do you mean?

Comment: It's just it's such a frequently asked question, there should be a big warning label when you add a jQuery tag to a question saying "Use the following syntax to make sure your events always fire" :)

Answer (score 0):

Check out the jQuery docs for [.on()](http://api.jquery.com/on/).
You need to use:

```
$('body').on('click', '.btn-comment, .btn-youtube', function(){ ... });
```

The problem with your code is that if `.btn-comment, .btn-youtube` are being inserted dynamically, then they probably don't exist at the point at which you're trying to attach your event handlers.
The above line of code attaches the handler to `body` but is only triggered by elements matching the second argument (`'.btn-comment, .btn-youtube'`).

And ideally, you'd replace `'body'` with the closest ancestor that the new elements are being inserted into.