# adding more clickable elements to a page then .on() doesnt work

Tags: javascript, jquery

so i have some code in a page that is like this

```
<div id="main">
  <div class='module' id ='test1'>1</div> 
  <div class='module' id ='test2'>2</div>
  <div class='module' id ='test3'>3</div>
  <div class='module' id ='test4'>4</div>
</div>
```

and a bit of js that has an event that is on the document.load

```
$('.module').on("click", function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('flipped')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');   
  } else {
      $('.module').removeClass('flipped');
      $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
  }  
});
```

this works fine until an element is added dynamically so lets say i add

```
  <div class='module' id ='test5'>5</div>
```

this is not going to be clickable because .on is not bound to this..

I have read posts here explaining that .on wont work... but i cannot find a solution..

can anyone help?

Comment: "_but i cannot find a solution_" - really?!  This is one of the most commonly asked questions about jQuery, and is also documented quite well in the jQuery docs.

Comment: possible duplicate of [On Click on Buttons when created on the fly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18958380/on-click-on-buttons-when-created-on-the-fly)

Comment: i am sorry i did have a look and couldnt find what was needed. sorry if i wasted peoples time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Delegate the events to the parent `#main`.

```
$('#main').on("click", ".module", function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('flipped')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');   
  } else {
      $('.module').removeClass('flipped');
      $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
  }  
});
```

Comment: sweet.. i tried something similar moving to main but i had slightly differnt (wrong) logic .. thanks will accept in 10

Answer (score 2):

Your JavaScript code executes only when the page loads. So after your page is loaded, your code is executed and you telling it to attach the `onclick` event handler to the elements having the class `module`. During initial page load there are only 4 such elements. So the event handler will be attached only to these elements (speaking very abstractly).

Now when a new element is added dynamically, events wouldnt fire because there are no handlers tied to them.

In this case you should take advantage of Event Delegation. You need to tie your event handler to the enclosing element (`#main` or some use `body`).

So your code would be like:

```
$('#main').on("click", ".module", function(){
  if ($(this).hasClass('flipped')) {
    $(this).toggleClass('flipped');   
  } else {
      $('.module').removeClass('flipped');
      $(this).toggleClass('flipped');
  }  
});
```

So the Event would be tied only to the static `#main` but when the event occurs, it knows where to find the targeted element because you have specified the target as `.module`.

**Have a look at this:**

> http://api.jquery.com/on/

***Event handlers are bound only to the currently selected elements; they must exist on the page at the time your code makes the call to .on().*** To ensure the elements are present and can be selected, perform event binding inside a document ready handler for elements that are in the HTML markup on the page. If new HTML is being injected into the page, select the elements and attach event handlers after the new HTML is placed into the page. Or, use delegated events to attach an event handler, as described next.

Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers. This element could be the container element of a view in a Model-View-Controller design, for example, or document if the event handler wants to monitor all bubbling events in the document. The document element is available in the head of the document before loading any other HTML, so it is safe to attach events there without waiting for the document to be ready.

In addition to their ability to handle events on descendant elements not yet created, another advantage of delegated events is their potential for much lower overhead when many elements must be monitored. On a data table with 1,000 rows in its tbody, this example attaches a handler to 1,000 elements:

```
$( "#dataTable tbody tr" ).on( "click", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

A delegated-events approach attaches an event handler to only one element, the tbody, and the event only needs to bubble up one level (from the clicked tr to tbody):

```
$( "#dataTable tbody" ).on( "click", "tr", function() {
  alert( $( this ).text() );
});
```

Note: Delegated events do not work for SVG.

Answer (score 1):

Try this...

`$('body').on("click", ".module" , function(){`